# how to map an image when its appear on hover

Tags: html, css

i m using a hover effect to change the images.when i hover on the first image it shows the another image which hasfew names which i want to link but coz this image is not visible in dreamweaver so i m unable to map it.

Here is the CSS for this:

```
div#content .promo{
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    width:170px;
    height:170px;
/*  border:1px solid #f00;*/
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
/*  border-radius:100px;*/

    }

#content .promo .mask {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1.0;
    position: absolute;
    transition: opacity 0.45s ease-in 0s;
    z-index: 1; 
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
/*  border-radius:100px;*/
}


#content .promo:hover .mask {
    opacity: 0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0); 
}
```

Here is the code for image in div:

```
<div id="content">
<div class="promo">
 <img src="http://pearlacademy.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Circles-back-01.png" />
    <div class="mask">
        <img src="http://pearlacademy.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/style.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, what do you wanna do?

Comment: actualy i want to map this image for linking
<img src="http://pearlacademy.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Circles-back-01.png" />
this image i want to map

Comment: You have three rows, so upon clicking on each row, it should take to a different URL, isn't it?

Comment: yuppp it is....so how is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go...

#### HTML

```
<div class="map">
    <img src="http://pearlacademy.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Circles-back-01.png" alt="Pearl" />
    <a href="http://www.google.com" class="link link1"></a>
    <a href="http://www.yahoo.com" class="link link2"></a>
    <a href="http://www.microsoft.com" class="link link3"></a>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.map {position: relative;}
.link {position: absolute; width: 150px; height: 40px;}
.link.link1 {top: 20px; left: 10px;}
.link.link2 {top: 60px; left: 10px;}
.link.link3 {top: 100px; left: 10px; height: 50px;}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/6uwRP/

---

Do you want something like this?

#### HTML

```
<div class="promo">
    <img src="http://pearlacademy.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Circles-back-01.png" />
    <img src="http://pearlacademy.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/style.png" class="hover" />
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.promo img.hover,
.promo:hover img {display: none;}
.promo:hover img.hover {display: inline;}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/dYExh/

Comment: thnks a lot dear but thats not what i actualy looking for....as i write above the whole code there are two different images and i want to map the second one which appear on hover.

Comment: yes exactly this...but when we hover over the image after that i want to link all those rows in that second image which has the links on it nd thanks for ur precious help

Comment: thanks buddy its working fine now nd now i m able to map the links on it.thanks a ton for ur help